# Sending a message if a new member says `test` in chat discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I do something if a user who joined less than 2 weeks ago sends a message in chat that has the `test` word in it ?

The only thing i could find was `discord.Member.joined_at`..which doesn't help me very much, just shows the time they joined.

I cannot use it like `if userjoin < 20160m:`
maybe something like deducting the current date with member join date to get the difference..

```
newjoined_words = ["test", "test2"]

@bot.listen("on_message")
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in newjoined_words:
        if word in msg.content.lower() and msg.author.joindate < 2w:
            await ctx.send("working")
```

*I know this may be a stupid question, but i never worked with datetime.

Comment: You're 20160 is in Minutes?

Comment: Yes. 2 weeks..in minutes (i know it is a bad code and i can probably use `2w`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract 2 weeks from [`msg.created_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.created_at) and check if `msg.author.joined_at` is before that using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```py
from datetime import timedelta

@bot.listen("on_message")
async def on_message(msg):
    max_join_date = msg.created_at - timedelta(weeks=2)
    for word in newjoined_words:
        if word in msg.content.lower() and msg.author.joined_at < max_join_date:
            await msg.channel.send("working")
```

Comment: Good job, implementing the `created_at`, missed that one

Comment: Thanks. It works. The only issue i have is that when i type `test2` i get the `working` message 2 times..but i am sure i can get a way around it. ty

Comment: @MihaiCristian Yes, because the loop continues after finding the first matching word. You could use a `return` or `break` to fix that.

Comment: Or just leave the `for`-Loop out.
`if msg.content.lower() in newjoined_words...:`

Answer (score 1):

[Discord Join date](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at)

[datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

[datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Compare them with the datetime modul

```py
import datetime

join_date = msg.author.joined_at # Not sure which discord.py version you're using
now = datetime.datetime.now()

comparison = now - joindate > datetime.timedelta(weeks=2) # returns True or False
```